# How to use \draw and \addplot with {pgfplots}

Tags: pgfplots, draw

I thought it was a simple task...but I am near to give up, because 
I am not able to draw a **simple** arrow between two points.
My MWE works only if I remove \pgfplotsset{compat=newest} **and**  \draw.
The pdf output is **erratic**, in fact, when something appears, the arrow is in a wrong position.
No one of the  similar examples found in Stack... works. I suspect I am missing
something fundamental
Many thanks for your help.

My MWE

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}  
%
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}  % added without success
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
%
\begin{axis}
%
    \addplot[domain=0.5:3, red,  thin] {(x^2-3)/2};
%
\end{axis}
%
\coordinate (orig) (0,0)
%
\coordinate (R) at (2,1/2)
%
\draw [->,thick,blue] (orig) -- (R)
%
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! You are missing a bunch of `;`. Use `\coordinate (orig) (0,0);
\coordinate (R) at (2,1/2);
\draw [->,thick,blue] (orig) -- (R);` (three semicolons added).

Answer (score 2):

Welcome! There are two things. You are missing three semicolons, and an `at`. But I guess the question is why the coordinates are not where you want them to be. This is because you define them in the ambient `tikzpicture` and not inside of the `axis`. Fixing this yields

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}  
%
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}  % added without success
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
%
\begin{axis}
%
    \addplot[domain=0.5:3, red,  thin] {(x^2-3)/2};
%
\coordinate (orig) at (0,0);
\coordinate (orig') at (0.5,-3/2);
\coordinate (R) at (2,1/2);
\end{axis}
%
\draw [->,thick,blue] (orig') -- (R);
%
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]